# How is power calculated in R? If the ratio of the delta and standard deviation remains the same, will power remain the same?

Tags: r

```
tmpSD = 10
tmpSD2 = 20
power.t.test(n=10,delta = 1*tmpSD,sd = tmpSD,sig.level=0.05,power=NULL,type="two.sample", alternative = c("two.sided"))

power.t.test(n=10,delta = 1*tmpSD2,sd = tmpSD2,sig.level=0.05,power=NULL,type="two.sample", alternative = c("two.sided"))
```

I have the above code in my R program. Both the first and second power.t.test result in the same power of 0.5619846. Does this mean that if my ratio of delta and standard deviation stay the same, so will my power?

EDIT:
In my test, I am running a power analysis to determine the minimum n needed to have 80% power in finding a statistically significant difference in Contribution and in Time. The standard deviations of the two are different. But, when running the following for loop to determine the power of each at different n's I obtain the exact same power at each n. I am nevertheless confused as to why the power in of each is identical at the same n. Why should my power to detect a statistically significant difference in decision time at a particular n be equal to my power to detect a statistically significant difference in contribution amount at the same n?

```
    sdContribution #15.39155
    sdTime #22.95667
    for (i in seq(20,200,by=10)){
    print(power.t.test(n=i,delta = 0.05*sdContribution,sd=sdContribution,sig.level = 0.05,power = NULL,type = "two.sample", alternative = c("two.sided")))
    print(power.t.test(n=i,delta = 0.05*sdTime,sd=sdTime,sig.level = 0.05,power = NULL,type = "two.sample", alternative = c("two.sided")))}
```

Comment: Well, it'll be the same standard deviation's worth of difference every time won't it? If the delta is X and the SD = X, then the z-score of delta is always 1.

Comment: Power depends on the non-central T-distribution. State your Null hypothesis and your Alternate hypothesis and we can start from there.

Comment: @thelatemail That makes sense. So then in my case, moving away from the example provided, these would then always get me the exact same result for different n values, correct?

Comment: The power depends on `n*delta/sd` or `sqrt(n)*delta/sd`, I don't remember. But it is not independent on `n`.